# How to detect a pointer to an arithmetic type using type traits and concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

How do I write a concept that detects a pointer to an arithmetic type?

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value;

template <typename T>
concept pointer_to_arithmetic = requires (T a) {
    { *a } -> arithmetic;
};

template <typename T>
void fn() {
    printf("fail\n");
}   

template <pointer_to_arithmetic T>
void fn() {
    printf("pass\n");
}   

struct s{};

int main() {
    fn<int>();
    fn<int*>();
    fn<s>();
    fn<s*>();
}
```

I tried the above and it compiles but doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Expected output is:

```
fail
pass
fail
fail
```

Instead I get:

```
fail
fail
fail
fail
```

It also doesn't work if I replace `*a` with `a[0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an expression `E` in a compound requirement, the type constraint predicate is fed `decltype((E))`<sup>[1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Compound_Requirementp)</sup>.

`decltype` encodes the value category of the expression in the type it deduces. Since `*p` is an lvalue expression. The deduced type is `T&` for some `T`.

So you may want to rewrite your pair of concepts as

```
template <typename T>
concept arithmetic_ref = std::is_arithmetic<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value;

template <typename T>
concept pointer_to_arithmetic = requires (T a) {
    { *a } -> arithmetic_ref ;
};
```

<sub>The atomic predicate could probably be better named.</sub>

---

Of course, this leaves a couple of questions open. Are you just duck-typing, and so any pointer-like type (even `std::optional` has `operator*`) is permissible? Or are you after only fundamental pointer types? How should the concept treat cv-qualified types (it currently doesn't permit them)?

Depending on how you answer those questions, the concept could be tweaked further.

Comment: I'd note this allows an overloaded `operator*`, e.g. `pointer_to_arithmetic<std::unique_ptr<int>>` is true. Might or might not be intended.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
template <typename T>
concept pointer_to_arithmetic = requires (T a) {
    requires std::is_arithmetic_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*a)>>;
    requires std::is_pointer_v<T>;
};

...

pointer_to_arithmetic<int>          -> false
pointer_to_arithmetic<float>        -> false
pointer_to_arithmetic<std::string*> -> false
pointer_to_arithmetic<int*>         -> true
pointer_to_arithmetic<float*>       -> true
```

The first line detects any type that can be dereferenced to an arithmetic type. Which might not what you need. So you need to add a second line that detects if `T` is indeed a pointer type.

Comment: `pointer_to_arithmetic<std::string *>  -> true`, doesn't look right.

Comment: Use _v instead of ::value

Answer (score 0):

The types given to your `arithmetic` trait are `int&` and `s&`, not `int` and `s`. One way you can fix this is to remove the reference from the `*a` expression:

```
template<typename T>
auto decay(T&& t) -> std::remove_cvref_t<T> {
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
concept pointer_to_arithmetic = requires (T a) {
    { decay(*a) } -> arithmetic;
};
```

Another way to go about this is to have `arithmetic` recognize references to arithmetic types as arithmetic because you can still *use* the variables in the same way. This is covered in another answer, albeit with a change to the concept name.